# Transaction roll back is not working in test case in @Nested class of JUnit5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, junit5

I use spring-boot, JUnit5, Mybatis.

```
@SpringJUnitJupiterConfig(classes = {RepositoryTestConfig.class})
@MapperScan
@Rollback
@Transactional
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private TestMapper testMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        User user = new User();
        testMapper.insert(user);    
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // (1) success rollback
    }

    @Nested
    class WhenExistData {
        @Test
        public void test2() {
            // (2) rollback not working
        }   
    }
}
```

(1) is working rollback. And the following log is output.

```
2017-05-26 22:21:29 [INFO ](TransactionContext.java:136) Rolled back transaction for test context ...
```

But, (2) is not working. I want to be able to roll back into `@Nested`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it in the following way..

```
@SpringJUnitJupiterConfig(classes = {RepositoryTestConfig.class})
@MapperScan
@Rollback
@Transactional
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private TestMapper testMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        User user = new User();
        testMapper.insert(user);    
    }

    @Nested
    @SpringJUnitJupiterConfig(classes = {RepositoryTestConfig.class})
    @MapperScan
    @Rollback
    @Transactional
    class WhenExistData {
        @Test
        public void test2() {
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind [creating an issue in the JUnit 5 project](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new), so some

Comment: Oh, damn I forgot to edit my comment. Argh! I accidentally linked to the wrong project, [this one](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5) might have been better. But we will see...

Comment: Neither JUnit 5 nor my personal `spring-test-junit5` repository is the appropriate place to raise such an issue. The correct place is Spring's JIRA issue tracker. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

This is to be expected: the *Spring TestContext Framework* has never supported "inheritance" for nested test classes.

Thus your "work around" is actually the correct way to achieve your goal at this point in time.

Note, however, that I may add support for "pseudo-inheritance" for *nested* test classes in conjunction with [SPR-15366](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15366).

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

// JUnit5
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {

    @Resource
    private TestMapper testMapper;

    @Test
    @Rollback
    @Transactional
    public void createByTimerId() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, testMapper.insert());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the annotation [NestedTestConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/NestedTestConfiguration.html) from Spring on the enclosing class did the trick for me. It seems that without it, the nested class won't inherit the config.

```
@NestedTestConfiguration(NestedTestConfiguration.EnclosingConfiguration.INHERIT)
```

So maybe on your TestClass you would have your current annotations and then:

```
@NestedTestConfiguration(NestedTestConfiguration.EnclosingConfiguration.INHERIT)
public class TestClass {
...
```