# Reload Spring application using DirtiesContext annotation doesn't work with nested classes

Tags: spring, junit5, spring-test, applicationcontext, junit-jupiter

I can't reload my spring application after each test into my nested classes:

```
/*...*/
@DirtiesContext( classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD )
public class MyTestClass {

    @Nested
    class MyNestedClass_1 {

        @Test
        void test_1() {
            /*...*/
        }

        @Test
        void test_2() {
            /*...*/
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class MyNestedClass_2 {
        /*..*/
    }
}
```

Whereas, it works very well without nested class:

```
/*...*/
@DirtiesContext( classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD )
public class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    void test_1() {
        /*...*/
    }

    @Test
    void test_2() {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Spring (boot) testing does not really work with nested test classes. The framework is not made for that.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring support for JUnit 5's `@Nested` class feature is currently limited. You can follow the progress to resolve this on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19930). For the time being, I guess you have to remove the nested classes and follow the progress closely.

You can also find a possible workaround at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44203244/transaction-roll-back-is-not-working-in-test-case-in-nested-class-of-junit5/44227179) by adding `@DirtiesContext( classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD )` on top of your nested class:

```
@DirtiesContext( classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD )
public class MyTestClass {

    @Nested
    @SpringBootTest
    @DirtiesContext( classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD )
    class MyNestedClass_1 {

        @Test
        void test_1() {
            /*...*/
        }

        @Test
        void test_2() {
            /*...*/
        }
    }

    @Nested
    @SpringBootTest
    @DirtiesContext( classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD )
    class MyNestedClass_2 {
        /*..*/
    }
}
```